# "What goes in" vs "What do you put in"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

My intiial question was - What would be best way to ask what the ingredients or components or resources that a particular item is made of?

But having spent some time on this today, Now I'm broadly curious on where either of these phrases are used/can be used.

PS: I'm not an native English speaker. Any help or information would be really helpful!

Comment: "What do you put in your [name of dish] that makes it taste so good?" might be a way of asking about a particular flavouring or ingredient.

Comment: I think the most natural expression is the one you started with: *What are the ingredients?*

Comment: You can also ask "What goes into this?"